# Best Exercise For V-Shape Without Weights

Tags: exercise, workout, muscle-gain, calisthenics, back

What is the best calisthenics exercise to get a V-Shape as fast as possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: V shape where exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to the V-shape created by a thin waist and wide latissimus dorsi, then I wholeheartedly recommend spending a lot of time doing pullups and its many variations.

As far as the slim waist goes, I'm not in a position to give advice, as I've had a slim waist by genetic predisposition. My challenge was always gaining mass, and for calisthenic mass gain around the upper back and lats, I've found pullups to be the be-all, end-all exercise for that.

I urge you to take your time with each rep, as eccentric overloading has been serenaded for its effect on muscle building. [Read more.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_training)

But more than that, I find it dubious that you are looking for ONE single exeercise, instead of a complete regimen. One single exercise will do nothing for you, unless it's part of a well-rounded workout program.

Comment: While a good answer, it's a bit incomplete. The deltoids should be included as rrirower points out, and esp with the shirt off, the obliques and low BF percentage are also fairly necessary.

Comment: I was pretty clear that if you're looking for ONE single exercise, you're dead in the water, and that a more filled out program is the way to go. I think it is implied that some muscle groups are neglected when opting for a single exercise.

Comment: True, I just thought that rather than saying "One exercise won't cut it", you could fend of the inevitable "Well what should I do then?" with an expansion. :)

Answer (score 0):

While building the lats is certainly a must for creating a “V” shape, there’s one muscle group that’s often overlooked.  Working all three heads of the [deltoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltoid_muscle) will add to upper body width thus enhancing the appearance of a “V” taper.  Additionally, building broader shoulders will create the illusion that that your waist is smaller.  This is important for those that cannot seem to develop narrow ripped abdominals.